# mysql select distinct statement (strict version?)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm running:
MySQL
Software version: 5.5.25 - Source distribution

I have a table like this:

```
Region | City
-----------------
quebec | montreal
_________________
quebec | montréal
```

The cities are written "montreal" and "montréal" with a french accent.

When I do 'select distinct City from table where Region="quebec"' it returns only

```
montreal
```

How do I get it to return both versions of montreal (with and without é)?

```
montreal
montréal
```

In other words how do I get sql to return both french and english spelling of the same word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
SELECT DISTINCT city COLLATE UTF8_BIN AS city
FROM table 
WHERE Region="quebec"
```

Comment: thank you! this is much closer, do you know how to make it return actual words that have accents, right now any word that has an accent is returned as a series of numbers e.g: "7361696e74652d68c3a96cc3a86e652d64652d6b616d6f757261736b61
"

Comment: :|   In my pc I prooved and it works fine... I don't know why it returns to you numbers... maybe could it be something about codification of your database or something... but to be honest I don't have the answer to that

Comment: had to add $cfg['DisplayBinaryAsHex'] = false; to phpmyadmin config file, thanks for your help!

Comment: you're welcome... glad to help :)